# What is the actual difference between pipe and subscribe?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angular-http-interceptors

I am developing an HttpInterceptor. For developing this interceptor, I am creating a service class as shown below:

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';

export class InterceptorClass implements HttpInterceptor{
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler){
        debugger
        req= req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.append('currentPlace','New Delhi')
        });
       return next.handle(req); //Doubt in this line
    }
}
```

Now my doubt is that, whenever I use `.pipe()` method after `next.handle(req)` it doesn't show any error. Code is as follows:

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';

export class InterceptorClass implements HttpInterceptor{
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler){
        debugger
        req= req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.append('currentPlace','New Delhi')
        });
        return next.handle(req).pipe(tap(()=>{

       }));
    }
}
```

But whenever I use `.subscribe()` after `next.handle()`, it gives error.
The code is as follows:

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class InterceptorClass implements HttpInterceptor{
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler){
        debugger
        req= req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.append('currentPlace','New Delhi')
        });
       return next.handle(req).subscribe((data)=>{

       });
    }
}
```

And error we get when we subscribe is:

```
      Type '(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) => Subscription' is not assignable to type '(req: HttpRequest<any>, next:
HttpHandler) => Observable<HttpEvent<any>>'.
        Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.
```

Why it is giving error when we `subscribe()` to `next.handle()`, because I have read that `next.handle()` returns an Observable hence we can subscribe it?

Comment: The intercept() method must return an Observable. pipe() transforms an Observable into another Observable, so that's correct. subscribe()... subscribes to the Observable and returns a Subscription, not an Observable, so that's not correct.

Comment: Why did you think they *would* be the same? Just because you *can* subscribe to something doesn't mean that's always the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pipe()` command is used to run the results from an Observable through a bunch of different processing commands, called operators.  The eventual return will still be an [Observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html).  [This is a good explanation of what pipeable operators are](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md).  My shortened version is that a pipeable operator is a function used to process an Observable's results.

The `subscribe()` command is used to get the results of an Observable, and it returns a [Subscription](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html).

A Subscription is not the same thing as an Observable, which is why they cannot be used interchangeably.  It might be worth noting that Without a `subscribe()`, the pipeable operators will never execute on the results returned from the Observable.

Comment: Thank you for this nice explanation. Could you please explain why it is giving error when I use "map" operator instead of "tap" operator in "pipe()" method?

Comment: Without seeing the code I'm not sure. Make sure that the map operator is imported.  Make sure that something is returned.

Comment: The map operator is imported. I think that "next.handle()" doesn't allows any manipulation of observable it returns, that's why it is giving error whenever I use map operator.

Comment: @johnny No idea what was on that link previously, but I think this is the updated doc that includes info on pipeable operators: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/operators.md

Answer (score 2):

When you subscribe, the results are returned within the function

The `pipe()` returns an observable to which you can subscribe to
pipe() allows you to process the original observable so that when you subscribe to it, you get a different value than originally emitted by the observable

Think of it like a pipeline where `pipe()` does some kind of processing before the value reaches where you have subscribed the value

Comment: Thank you for this nice explanation. Could you please explain why it is giving error when I use "map" operator instead of "tap" operator in "pipe()" method?